# Text should not wrap inside td

Tags: html, html-table

I have following table it shows like this:

```
ABC                                                         A B C
                                                            123
Hello
```

But I don't want text on the end to wrap. I want it to show it in one line like this A B C 123. In one line. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
<table width="100%">
                        <tr>                            
                                <hr style="width:100%;"></hr>                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td align="left">ABC
                          </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                    <div class="n" >A B C </div>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          Hello
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: what is wrapping? everything is where it should be as you specified.. do you want 'hello' on the same row as the others? Im not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @PAULDAWG - ABC 123 is not on same line. That is what i want to be in same line at. And person who gave -1 can please explain the reason?

Comment: oh i see. what does class n specify within the css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a div is a block level element that fills the entire width of its container by default,

change it to a span and the 123 will be next to the abc:

```
<td align="right">
     <span class="n" >A B C </span>
     <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
</td>
```

In cases where the table is too narrow, it will still wrap, so you would have to pad out with non breaking spaces if you never wanted it to wrap, eg:

```
<td align="right">
     <span class="n" >A&nbsp;B&nbsp;C</span>&nbsp;
     <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following value in your TD tag:

```
<TD NOWRAP>
```

Comment: this will only affect the text within the TD tag